# Deriving Single Index Model (Market Model)

Tags: capm, sharpe-ratio, expected-return, market-model

$R_{it}=\alpha_i+\beta_i\cdot R_{mkt}+\epsilon_{it}$

- $R_{it}$ is the return of the stock of observation
- $R_{mkt}$ is the return of the reference market
- $\beta_i$ is the regression coefficient between the observed stock and the reference market
- $\alpha_i$ is the regression intercept between the observed stock and reference
- $\epsilon_{it}$ is the error (a random variable with expectation zero and finite variance)

First of all can someone help me to understand what $\epsilon_{it}$ represents in the model and how one should compute it. Considering it is a random variable which distribution is often used? Why expectation zero?

Secondly from the empirical point of view which is the best practice in computing $R_{mkt}$ in relation to this model? (i.e. simple annual mean, annual ewm etc.)

Comment: The residuals, $\epsilon _{it}$, follow a Normal distribution with zero mean and some variance. That's the definition of noise (if it wasn't noise and you knew it, you could and should model it). As per $R_{mt}$, there's no best practice: if you have developed a good model, either based on econometrics, machine learning, personal experience or dark magic, you should be already working for some of the biggest funds out there.

Comment: $R_{mt}$ is the return on portfolio broad enough to represent "the market" as a whole. Numerous indices of market performance exist (such as S&P500) and are used for this purpose. The most common practice is to measure these returns on a monthly (or sometimes daily) basis. (It is important not to use any averaging or smoothing, but to use the raw returns).

Comment: @Alex C: I thought he was talking about forecasts rather than parameters estimation.

Comment: Good point. The whole question is not as clear as it could be.

Comment: @AlexC thank you for your reply too. What I would like to understand is considering a given index (of course it should be representative of the stock observed etc.) how one should computes Rmt in order to obtain with this model a consistent and good result? I mean there is no sense in implementing a more complex model for estimating return of a stock (more complex compared to i.e estimating stock return simply with annualized average of daily returns) using "low quality" inputs (i.e computing Rmt as simple annualized average of daily returns - thus limiting the model itself).

Comment: @Nipper: the hypothesis is that $\epsilon_{t}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2\right)$ (white noise). So you estimate the parameters, plug them into the equation and give a look at the difference between the results and the actual values. That difference, a.k.a. "residuals", is a time series with measurable moments, that are mean and variance. If the model is good, the mean is not statistically different than zero; meanwhile, the variance has a value that you can estimate by using a simple estimator (average squared error). This is the simplest hypothesis for the residuals density.

Comment: As said by others, the residual $\varepsilon$ represents a “model error”. It summarises everything which your regressor $R_{mkt}$ fails to explain. We call it an idiosyncratic component. When running the regression (in excel or R or elsewhere), you get the residuals as an output. Secondly, you do not compute $R_{mkt}$. You observe it. It’s just the return on the total value weighted CRSP sample (or simply the S&P 500). That’s given. You just download it. Note that you should use excess returns on the left and right hand side.